# Arborvitae has been cut beyond the growth line, will they ever grow back?

Tags: diagnosis, shrubs

They look like heck. All I see is branches in the 3 foot spot in the middle of my 15 foot arborvitae where the gardeners trimmed back too deep. All I see are brown twigs. Will it grow back?

Comment: Hi and  welcome. Please post a picture of you can